Logstash does not output correct timestamp
I have 2 log need to parsing. Grok are fine but #logstash does not get correct timestamp ( it always get my local machine timestamp " "@timestamp" => 2024-05-20T09:22:23.361Z,"). Could you please have a look and give advice. Thanks everyone
message 1:
enter image description here
config 1:
enter image description here
message 2:
enter image description here
config 2:
enter image description here

Please explain how your question relates to the topic of Stack overflow which is software development and post all of your config and output as text, not as images.

config for message 1: input {
beats {
port => 5044
}
}
filter
{
grok {
match => { "message" => "(?%{DATE_EU}%{SPACE}%{TIME})%{GREEDYDATA:rest}" }
}
date {
match => [ "dts", "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
target => "@timestamp"
timezone => "UTC"
}
}
output {
stdout {
codec => rubydebug
}
}

config for message 2:
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}
}
filter
{
grok {
match => { "message" => "(?%{DAY}%{SPACE}%{MONTH}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{TIME}%{SPACE}%{YEAR})%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:rest}" }
}
date {
match => [ "dts", "ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss YYYY" ]
target => "@timestamp"
}
}
output {
stdout {
codec => rubydebug
}
}

Add everything to the question itself, not in the comments.
